# C Text algorithms

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm curious about few things about text algorithms.

For example we have binary word : 1011101110001101
And how to search for specific fixed subsequences in this word ?

For example how to find longest fixed subsequence(lets call it LFS) in word which has same amount of 1's and 0's ?

And another, how to find LFS with more 1's than 0's in it ?

Example : 
word :1001010
we are searching for LFS with same amount of 1's and 0's.

So this LFS would be 100101

But with more 1's than 0's we'll have : 101

How to solve this faster than O(n^2)?

Chris.

Comment: Is this homework? Sounds a lot like it...

Comment: C or C++? Title says C, tags say C++, languages are not the same, contrary to common (mis)belief.

Comment: No it's not homework, i'm trying to learn curious things because i'm going to try in IT contest in next year.

Comment: Thinking about it, no method comes to mind that would allow you to do this under O(n^2). The first pass would create all the substrings and the next pass would compare all substrings with length 1 to the collected substrings. The next pass all length 2 and so forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a [**Trie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) out of the input.

That will help you find LFS strings.

You can change the creation algorithm to count 1s and 0s, and then you'll easily find those numbers on the substring nodes.

Look at [**Suffix Tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) as well..

Creation = O(n)
For the search, you'll probably do something like BFS which also be like O(N)